# ARM NEON to aarch64

Tags: arm, simd, arm64, neon

I have code for ARM NEON armv7-a:

```
vst2.u8   {d1,d3}, [%1]!
```

I port it to aarch64 like that:

```
st2 {v1.8b,v3.8b},[%1],#16
```

and got an error: *Error: invalid register list at operand 1 -- `st2 {v1.8b,v3.8b},[x1],#16'*

In accordance with doc this is valid:

```
ST2 {Vt.<T>, Vt+2.<T>}, vaddr
```

I can't figure out the problem.

p.s. if i change it like

```
st2 {v1.8b,v2.8b},[%1],#16
```

the compiler doesn't break with error message

Comment: Which doc are you looking at? The _ARM®
 A64 Instruction Set Architecture_ (DDI 0596) says this: `<Vt> Is the name of the first or only SIMD&FP register to be transferred, encoded in the "Rt" field.
<Vt2> Is the name of the second SIMD&FP register to be transferred, encoded as "Rt" plus 1 modulo 32.`

Comment: @Michael, I was looking at [this](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0489/g/neon-and-vfp-programming/neon-load-and-store-element-and-structure-instructions/vldn-and-vstn--multiple-n-element-structures-?lang=en) and [this](https://www.element14.com/community/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/41836-102-1-229511/ARM.Reference_Manual.pdf) documents

Comment: `d1,d3` are the high 64 bits of 2 consecutive 16-byte `q` registers in 32-bit mode.  `v1.8b` and `v2.8b` are the low 64 bits of 2 consecutive 16-byte vector registers in 64-bit mode.  (I didn't check the 32-bit instruction to see if arbitrary pairs could be encoded, or only reg, reg+2 in 32-bit mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am refering to the [ARM a64 instruction set architecture](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0596/a/DDI_0596_ARM_a64_instruction_set_architecture.pdf) here, which was last updated in 2018.

The first link in your comment was only about the aarch32 instruction set. The second link was about the aarch64 instruction set, but it's titled as **iterim** in the pdf title and was published 2011. The format

```
ST2 { <Vt>.<T>, <Vt+2>.<T> }, vaddr
```

is mentioned there (page 89), but this is not included in the current version.

### Encoding of `ST2`

In the current version, `ST2` is coded for multiple data structures as follows (see page 1085):

```
┌───┬───┬──────────┬───┬───────┬──────┬────┬───────┬───────┐
│ 0 │ Q │ 00110010 │ I │ mmmmm │ 1000 │ ss │ nnnnn │ ttttt │
└───┴───┴──────────┴───┴───────┴──────┴────┴───────┴───────┘
                           Rm          size    Rn      Rt
```

There are three types of offset the instruction can be used with:

- No offset (`Rm == 000000` and `I == 0`):

  ```
  ST2 { <Vt>.<T>, <Vt2>.<T> }, [<Xn|SP>]
  ```
- Immediate offset (`Rm == 111111` and `I == 1`):

  ```
  ST2 { <Vt>.<T>, <Vt2>.<T> }, [<Xn|SP>], <imm>
  ```
- Register offset (`Rm != 111111` and `I == 1`):

  ```
  ST2 { <Vt>.<T>, <Vt2>.<T> }, [<Xn|SP>], <Xm>
  ```

`<imm>` is `#16` or `#32` here, regarding to `Q`. Only the first register's index `t` is saved in the encoding here. The second register's index is always calculated as `t+1 mod 32`.

That's why you got the error: the registers must follow one another. There is simply not enough space to encode the second register separately. The two index registers already take up too much lot of space.

### Consideration

Wouldn't it be possible to encode the second register? In the case `I == 0`, `Rm` is set to `00000`, but that's just conventional. This register could be used for our purpose, but only in the case that no immediate or register offset is specified.

I also see the reason why the format with `<Vt+2>` was not adopted from the draft: it can only be coded for this special case. The implementation would make the implementation of the chip more complex and simply not worthwhile.